# Show uncommon part of the line

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I have two files which contain paths. I want to compare the two files and show only uncommon part of the line.

1.txt:

```
/home/folder_name/abc
```

2.txt:

```
/home/folder_name/abc/pqr/xyz/mnp
```

Output I want:

```
/pqr/xyz/mnp
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not use diff ? Do you need just the different part ?

Comment: Is one always a prefix of the other? Is 1 always a prefix of 2, or can it be the other way round?

Answer (score 1):

This bit of awk does the job:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[++i]=$0; next}
{
    b[++j]=$0; 
    if(length(a[j])>length(b[j])) {t=a[j]; a[j]=b[j]; b[j]=t}
    sub(a[j],"",b[j]);
    print b[j]
}' 2.txt 1.txt  # or 2.txt 1.txt, it doesn't matter
```

- Write the line from the first file to the array `a`.
- Write the line from the second to `b`.
- Swap `a[j]` and `b[j]` if `a[j]` is longer than `b[j]` (this might not be necessary if the longer text is always in `b`).
- Remove the part found in `a[j]` from `b[j]` and print `b[j]`.

This is a general solution; it makes no assumption that the match is at the start of the line, or that the contents of one file's line should be removed from the other. If you can afford to make those assumptions, the script can be simplified.

If the match may occur more than once on the line, you can use `gsub` rather than `sub` to perform a global substitution.

Comment: Does this still print the line even if the line is identical in both files ? Also it doesnt seem to work for me in a file with multiple lines ?

Comment: @Jidder in answer to your first question, I wasn't aware that was a requirement. I have made an edit to address the second issue. Thanks.

Comment: The first question was because it was still printing the line if it was identical, which would look to the user like that was a difference between them, anyway your edit has solved both problems. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

This script will compare all lines in the file and only output the change in the line.
First it counts the number of lines in the first file.

Then i start a loop that will iterate for the number of lines.
Declare two variable that are the same line from both files.
Compare the lines and if they are the same output that they are.
If they are not then replace duplicate parts of the string with nothing(effectively removing them)
I used `:` as the seperator in `sed` as your variables contain `/`. So if they contain `:` then you may want to consider changing them.

Probably not the most efficient solution but it works.

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMOFLINES=$(wc -l < "1.txt")
echo $NUMOFLINES

for ((i = 1 ; i <= $NUMOFLINES ; i++)); do

f1=$(sed -n $i'p' 1.txt)
f2=$(sed -n $i'p' 2.txt)

if [[ $f1 < $f2 ]]; then
        echo -n "Line $i:"
        sed 's:'"$f1"'::' <<< "$f2"
elif  [[ $f1 > $f2 ]]; then
        echo -n "Line $i:"
        sed 's:'"$f2"'::' <<< "$f1"
else
        echo "Line $i: Both lines are the same"
fi

echo ""

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have strings in `1.txt` and in `2.txt` following code will do.

```
paste 1.txt 2.txt | 
while read a b; 
do 
    if [[ ${#a} -gt ${#b} ]];
    then
        echo ${a/$b}; 
    else
        echo ${b/$a};
    fi;
done;
```

This is how it works on my system,

```
shiplu@:~/test/bash$ cat 1.txt 
/home/shiplu/test/bash
/home/shiplu/test/bash/hello/world
shiplu@:~/test/bash$ cat 2.txt 
/home/shiplu/test/bash/good/world
/home/shiplu/test/bash
shiplu@:~/test/bash$ paste 1.txt 2.txt | 
> while read a b; 
> do 
>     if [[ ${#a} -gt ${#b} ]];
>     then
>         echo ${a/$b}; 
>     else
>         echo ${b/$a};
>     fi;
> done;
/good/world
/hello/world
```

Comment: I did and it doesn't, you use `while read a b` which has the variable space seperated. Due to you using paste then it will consider the second word from `a` as `b` and b will also contain the data that is supposed to be in `b`

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use bash, you could try this one:

```
echo $(diff <(grep -o . 1.txt) <(grep -o . 2.txt) \
| sed -n '/^[<>]/ {s/^..//;p}' | tr -d '\n')
```

It does a character-by-character comparison using `diff` (where `grep -o .` gives an intermediate line for each character to be fed to line-wise diff), and just prints the differences (intermediate diff output lines starting with markers `<` or `>` omitted, then joining lines with tr).

If you have multiple lines in your input (which you did not mention in your question) then try something like this (where `%` is a character not contained in your input):

```
diff <(cat 1.txt | tr '\n' '%' | grep -o .) \
 <(cat 2.txt | tr '\n' '%' | sed -e 's/%/%%/g' | grep -o .) \
| sed -n '/^[<>]/ {s/^..//;p}' | tr -d '\n' | tr '%' '\n'
```

This extends the single-line solution by adding line end markers (e.g. %) which diff is forced to include in its output by adding % on the left and %% on the right.

Answer (score 0):

If both the files have always a single line in each, then below works:

```
perl -lne '$a=$_ if($.==1);print $1 if(/$a(.*)/ && $.==2)' 1.txt 2.txt
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat 1.txt
/home/folder_name/abc
> cat 2.txt
/home/folder_name/abc/pqr/xyz/mnp
> perl -lne '$a=$_ if($.==1);print $1 if(/$a(.*)/ && $.==2)' 1.txt 2.txt
/pqr/xyz/mnp
>
```

Comment: thats not bash! its perl!